# Post removes any text from post that's following special characters

Tags: encoding, characters

I have a weird problem with losing content in posts with special characters in it.

Let's say I inserted the following content into a post:

---

Hello,

👿

This is my post

---

Wordpress would remove the special character (👿) and the text following, and save the post like this:

---

Hello,

---

I tried playing the charset in wp-config file but no luck.

Comment: What is the database character set?

Comment: the default, utf8

Comment: I have the same problem on localhost. Can any one else duplicate this?

Comment: What is that character?

Comment: Any character like this: &#127775;

Comment: What's `posts` table collation?